# Devise: Authenticate one model through another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Say I have a simple `User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord    
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable,
         :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
end
```

As well as a model for companies:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  validates :admin, :name, presence: true

  delegate :email, to: :admin

  def email=(email)
    self.admin = User.find_by(email: email) ||
                 User.new(email: email)
  end
end
```

With routes like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # API

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: "json" } do
    namespace :v1 do
      # Companies
      resources :companies

      # Users
      resources :users, except: :destroy

      devise_scope :user do
        post "/users/sign_in", to: "sessions#create"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With a `SessionsController` that looks like:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
      rescue_from ActionController::ParameterMissing, with: :invalid_login

      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create
      protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
      respond_to :json

      def create
        @user = Forms::SigninForm.new(signin_params)

        if @user.save
          @user = @user.user
          render "api/v1/users/show"
        else
          invalid_login(@user.errors)
        end
      end

      def destroy
        sign_out(resource_name)
      end

      def invalid_login(messages)
        render json: { errors: messages }
      end

      private

      def signin_params
        user_params.merge(auth_options: auth_options)
      end

      def user_params
        params.require(:user)
              .permit(:email, :password)
              .merge(warden: warden)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Where the `SigninForm` is defined like:

```
module Forms
  class SigninForm < BaseFormObject
    validate :user_exists

    attr_reader :email, :password, :warden

    def save
      return false if invalid?

      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        user.auth_tokens.create(portal: portal_request?)
        unless portal_request?
          user
            .auth_tokens
            .second_to_last&.
            destroy
        end
      end

      true
    end

    def user
      @user ||=
        begin
          warden.authenticate(auth_options) ||
            User.find_by(admin_password_query, email, password)
        end
    end

    private

    def admin_password_query
      "email ilike ? and admin_password = ?".freeze
    end

    def user_exists
      return if user.present?
      errors.add(:user, "Invalid email or password.")
    end

    def portal_request?
      @portal_request
    end

    def user_params
      {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    end

    def auth_options
      {
        scope: @scope,
        recall: @recall
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a simple and straight forward way to delegate authentication for a `Company` to it's `admin`? In such a way that, when a company is created, the associated `User` admin is the one who holds the auth token and password, and when the a user would like to sign in as a company - the password is checked against the user model, not the company.

Is there a way to, perhaps, use a custom devise strategy?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add more authenticated models to devise. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

You could than create a custom action, where you call `sign_in(@company)`. Only allow this action for admins of the company. Thats it!

Comment: I like your suggestion, but it may not make the change completely clear to others. Would you be able to add an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To update, I came up with a solution that was simple enough, at least for me.  During that time I learned about warden's use of the [strategy pattern](https://www.harrywhelchel.com/warden-a-review/), which allowed me to refactor the `SigninForm` by pulling out any of means of authentication seen in the form object (i.e: finding user by email and an "admin password") into actual warden strategies, registering them with warden's `Manager` middleware, and then simply listing the authentication strategies used in the `SigninForm` that we finally pass to warden's `Proxy` class [which runs these strategies](https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/v1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb#L103) until one succeeds (or they all fail).

So, we can define strategies [like](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Strategies):

```
# in /config/initializers/auth_strategies.rb

require "devise/strategies/authenticatable"

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class AdminAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        params[:user] && params[:email] || params[:password]
      end

      def authenticate!
        pass unless params[:user]

        user = User.find_by("email ilike ? and admin_password = ?",
                            params[:email],
                            params[:password])

        success!(user) if user
        fail!
      end
    end

    class CompanyAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def valid?
        params[:company]
      end

      def authenticate!
        user = User.find_by_email(params[:company][:email])
        if user&.valid_password?(params[:company][:password])
          if Company.find_by(admin_id: user.id)
            success!(user)
          else
            fail!
          end
        else
          fail!
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Register them with the `Manager` middleware:

```
# in /config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
   config.warden do |manager|
     manager.strategies.add(
       :company_authenticatable,
       Devise::Strategies::CompanyAuthenticatable
     )
     manager.strategies.add(
       :admin_authenticatable,
       Devise::Strategies::AdminAuthenticatable
     )
   end
end
```

Finally, refactoring the form object and simply passing in used strategies to warden there:

```
module Forms
  class SigninForm < BaseFormObject
    validate :user_exists
    validate :user_administrates_company, if: :company_signin?

    attr_reader :email, :password, :warden

    def save
      return false if invalid?

      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        user.auth_tokens.create(portal: portal_request?)
        unless portal_request?
          user
            .auth_tokens
            .second_to_last&.
            destroy
        end
      end

      true
    end

    def user
      @user ||=
        begin
          warden.authenticate(*strategies, auth_options)
        end
    end

    def company
      @company ||=
        user && Company.find_by(admin_id: user&.id)
    end

    private

    def user_exists
      return if user.present?
      errors.add(:user, "Invalid email or password.")
    end

    def user_administrates_company
      return if company.present?
      errors.add(:company, "Invalid email or password.")
    end

    def portal_request?
      @portal_request
    end

    def company_signin?
      @resource.eql?("company")
    end

    protected

    def strategies
      %i[database_authenticatable admin_authenticatable company_authenticatable]
    end

    def auth_options
      {}
    end
  end
end
```